# SQL Server 2014 installation stuck (hung up) or taking very long time to finish

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2014 but it stays in the same spot (Install_VCRuntime_Cpu32_Action) for hours. It's already the third time I'm trying to install so I don't know what else to do.

SQL Server 2014 Installation

[image]

Comment: Did you verify that only one install is going on? I assume you restarted between each install? Also, what version of windows and SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Yes, it was only one install, yes i did restarted between installs and my OS is Windows 10 v.1607 and it's the SQL Server 2014 v.12.0.2000.8

Comment: Ok, I assum your computer has all updates and that the hang isn't the computer trying to install updates. Could you check the logs following this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702(v=sql.120).aspx and see what the error is?

Comment: Related post - [SQL Server 2017 Developer edition installation is stuck (hung up) endlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47432390/465053)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I observed this very same issue in one of my colleague's windows 10 box with SQL Server 2014 Enterprise installer as well. As mentioned in [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/741476/sql-server-2012-express-setup-issue) MS connect bug you can try either of the below mentioned options:

1. As mentioned by KevinMS in comments tab :

> I used task manager and killed the Windows Installer instances,
>   clicked Retry and the installation completed. What a beat down.

You can kill the Windows Installer process as shown below:

[image]

2. As mentioned by Jonathan Dyke in workarounds tab:

> It's fixed!
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2820068
>
> I tested this solution with 2014 express and can confirm that using
>   /SkipInstallerRunCheck works as advertised. The installer no longer
>   goes into an endless loop when it can't shut down msiserver.

For my colleague who was facing this issue with SQL Server 2014 setup, solution # 1 above worked.

**Regarding SQL Server 2017** : My colleague faced exactly same issue on SQL Server 2017 also. We didn't see the "Windows Installer" app in processes tab on his machine. So we went with solution # 2 i.e. launch the installer as `Setup.exe /SkipInstallerRunCheck` and it worked for him. While running from PowerShell console the command looks like `.\Setup.exe /SkipInstallerRunCheck`.

Comment: Thanks but this does not work for SQL Server 2017 Developer edition whose download file is "SQLServer2017-SSEI-Dev.exe" the parameter is not recognized

Comment: `.\Setup.exe /SkipInstallerRunCheck` worked for me, thanks

Comment: This also seems to work for SQL Server 2016 with SP2, thanks :)

Comment: `/SkipInstallerRunCheck` seems to fix a myriad of such problems.  Mine was not quite what the OP posted, but a hang of the SQL 2019 installer launched from an InstallShield MSI script, just like the scenario in the MS support link above.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue on SQL express 2014. When I went to check there was indeed a Windows Installer running. I killed that process & SQL proceeded to install just fine.

Found this here:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/483582-ms-sql-2014-install-freezing

Comment: I've fixed with solution #1 as well on MSSQL Express 2017, by killing two Windows Installer processes. Thank you!